# Bash to execute when network is established

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to run a script on Ubuntu when the network is connected. The main aim should be to update the time as soon as the first connection to Internet is established.

I know that scripts from `/etc/network/if-up.d/` should be executed. Placing a script in this folder with just

`date -u > /tmp/test.time`

is not executed cause `/tmp/` doesn't show any `test.time`. I don't know if this has an influence, but I have configured a static IP-address.

So my question is how to execute a script (resp. commands) when the connection to Internet is established? *and* How to install it to run after boot?

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate for sysadmin.com, superuser.com, or unix.stackexchange.com. It's a system administration question, not a programming question.

Comment: Make sure your script is executable, has the proper `#!` header and use full path to `date` in case it isn't in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Upstart: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/
You can hook-up your scripts to various system events. Their [documentation](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) explains that all. I think you need `net-device-up` event, look for it in documentation.

Comment: Thx for the link. I need to dig further and cannot really say YES or NO, cause I'm running into other troubles for the very moment. Thx anyway.